# shouldReinviteDisconnectedPlayer not being called in iOS 10.3

Tags: ios, swift, gamekit

I am using the default GKMatchmakerViewController for matchmaking using the following code

```
let request = GKMatchRequest()
request.defaultNumberOfPlayers = 2
let matchmakerViewController = GKMatchmakerViewController(matchRequest: request)!
matchmakerViewController.matchmakerDelegate = self
self.present(matchmakerViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

My phone and simulator are both running this and are able to find each other and enter a match. I am also able to exchange data using

```
match.sendData(toAllPlayers: data, with: .reliable)
```

Everything is fine until I put one of the apps in the background. I am able to trigger this event

```
public func match(_ match: GKMatch, player: GKPlayer, didChange state: GKPlayerConnectionState) {
    print("player disconnected")
}
```

The problem is reconnecting the user once the app is active again. This never gets called.

```
public func match(_ match: GKMatch, shouldReinviteDisconnectedPlayer player: GKPlayer) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

Is there something about my match that is preventing this from being called? I see this in the header files

> // This method is called when the match is interrupted; if it returns YES, a new invite will be sent to attempt reconnection. This is supported only for 1v1 games

Does my match not count as a 1v1 game? If it does, where should I be expecting the new invite?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience the shouldReinviteDisconnectedPlayer method does not get called the first time the match is disconnected.  It is called all subsequent times.  I don't know why it isn't called that first time.